# CSS styling disappear in adding div

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie to CSS .. I was wondering why adding a div cause change in the styles !!

This is my HTML

```
<div class="companies_body">
        @foreach($companies as $company)
        <img src="img/{{$company->image}}" alt="" class="comp_img">
        <div class="company_description">
        {{($company->description)}}
        </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>
```

and this is the image style

```
.companies_body .comp_img{
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}
```

here the image height is bounded to only 30% of it's original height and working  .. but by modifying the HTML to be like that

```
<div class="companies_body">
            @foreach($companies as $company)
            <div class="test">
            <img src="img/{{$company->image}}" alt="" class="comp_img">
            <div class="company_description">
            {{($company->description)}}
            </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach

        </div>
```

the styling of the `img` disappear !!

Comment: Your div **.test** has no height, therefor the image inside it has 30% height of nothing. Give **.test** some height and you can delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

What has happened in your earlier code is that the child of companies_body is directly comp_img … So when you access it, you put it like :
.companies_body .comp_img // Which is what you have done.

Now, you add a div test, so .comp_img is a child of .test which in turn is a child of .companies_body and hence the img css disappears.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where did you add .test?

Comment: Oh well, I just thought you asked why adding a div was causing changes to the styling… for which I answered, I guess. Now after adding .test the style is not being accessed is what you're saying ? When you add an element, you need to change the other styles with respect to the element also … I was able to access the class  [link](http://www.cssdesk.com) though, after adding the test class to the css.